# Deface link_to Rails Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree, deface

I am new to Spree. I want to deface `link_to` rails helper.

i have `spree/checkout/_new_user` file and it contain following:

```
<%= link_to Spree.t(:login_as_existing), spree.login_path %>
```

i want to add `remote: true` to above `link_to` using deface.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace links

```
Deface::Override.new(virtual_path: 'checkout/_new_user', 
                         name: 'add remote true to link", 
                         replace: "erb[loud]:contains('link_to Spree.t(:login_as_existing), spree.login_path'), 
                         text: "<%= link_to Spree.t(:login_as_existing), spree.login_path, remote: true %>")
```